# Lightgallery - Comment Box be responsive

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-comments, lightgallery

I would like to display the `lightGallery` with the comment box but it must be responsive for mobile devices. How can I do that? Will it need plugin customization?

Thanks for helping.